# Why is pandas map slower than list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, pandas, list-comprehension

Does someone know why pandas/numpy map is slower then list comprehension?
I thought I could optimize my code replacing the list comprehensions by map. Since map doesn't need the list append operation.

Here is one test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(100000))
```

**List comprehension:**

```
%timeit -n 10 df["A"] = [x for x in df[0]]

#10 loops, best of 3: 550 ms per loop
```

**Pandas map**

```
%timeit -n 10 df["A"] = df[0].map(lambda x: x)

#10 loops, best of 3: 797 ms per loop
```

**Update**
based on comment bellow - list comprehension and map calling same function f, list comprehension faster

```
def f(x):
    return x

%timeit -n 100 df["A"] = df[0].map(f)

#100 loops, best of 3: 475 ms per loop

%timeit -n 100 df["A"] = [f(x) for x in df[0]]

#100 loops, best of 3: 399 ms per loop
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve using `df[0].map(lambda x: x)`?

Comment: This is not a fair test. `map` has to call a `lambda` function at each value (function calls have an overhead), whereas the list comprehension can bypass this. Try defining `f = lambda x: x` and then do `df["A"] = [f(x) for x in df[0]]` instead. That'll be much closer in performance.

Comment: @MaxU lambda x: x was an example to illustrate that using list comprehension instead of map where it is possible can be faster. E.g converting a column with UnixEpoch to DateTime.

Comment: @ajcr thanks for the comment. If list comprehension also calls a function it is still a little bit faster then map.

Comment: On my machine using `map` is actually slightly faster than list comprehension. I don't think one option is necessarily faster than the other for function application (they basically do the same thing when function application is involved), so I'm not sure if your question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my results:

list comprehension:

```
In [33]: %timeit df["A"] = [x for x in df[0]]
10 loops, best of 3: 72.6 ms per loop
```

simple column assignment:

```
In [34]: %timeit df["A"] = df[0]
The slowest run took 5.75 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 661 µs per loop
```

using `.map()` method:

```
In [35]: map_df = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 10**6, 100000))

In [36]: %timeit df["A"] = df[0].map(map_df)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.8 ms per loop
```